PHP 7 CURL post request over 1024 characters timing out
I'm working in a Cake PHP 2 project running PHP 7.4. I'm trying to make a POST request via CURL to a server. I'm getting some odd behaviour with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. I need to send my data as an encoded JSON array so I'm doing json_encode, but it seems that when checking the character count of this, anything over 1024 causes curl to timeout and not send?
I've checked max_input_vars which is default to 1,000, and my post_max_size is 2048M so plenty big enough, what's going on here?
An identical problem back in 2009 is here, but trying this, no luck.
/**
 * Perform a request to store the application.
 * TODO: WIP
 */
private function storeApplication()
{
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getEndpoint());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        $customer = $this->application;

        $fields = json_encode([
            'product_type' => 'foo',
            'data_source' => 'foo',
            'data' => [
                'ApiKey' => 'foo',
                'AffId' => 'foo',
                'Application' => [
                    'SubAffId' => '',
                    'ReqRepaymentTerm' => $this->formatField($customer, 'ReqRepaymentTerm'),
                    'AppTitle' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppTitle'),
                    'AppFirstName' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppFirstName'),
                    'AppLastName' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppLastName'),
                    'AppDOBDay' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppDOBDay'),
                    'AppDOBMonth' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppDOBMonth'),
                    'AppDOBYear' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppDOBYear'),
                    'AppMaritalStatus' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppMaritalStatus'),
                    'AppDependants' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppDependants'),
                    'AppHomeStatus' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppHomeStatus'),
                    'AppAddressYears' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppAddressYears'),
                    'AppHouseNumber' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppHouseNumber'),
                    'AppPostCode' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppPostCode'),
                    'AppStreet' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppStreet'),
                    'AppTown' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppTown'),
                    'AppCounty' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppCounty'),
                    'AppEmail' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppEmail'),
                    'AppMobilePhone' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppMobilePhone'),
                    'EmpIncomeType' => $this->formatField($customer, 'EmpIncomeType'),
                    'EmpEmployerName' => $this->formatField($customer, 'EmpEmployerName'),
                    'EmpIndustry' => 25,
                    'EmpEmployedMonths' => $this->formatField($customer, 'EmpEmployedMonths'),
                    'EmpPayFrequency' => $this->formatField($customer, 'EmpPayFrequency'),
                    'EmpNetMonthlyPay' => $this->formatField($customer, 'EmpNetMonthlyPay'),
                    'AppLoanPurpose' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppLoanPurpose'),
                    'AppLoanPrposeOther' => '',
                    'AppHousingSpend' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppHousingSpend'),
                    'AppCreditSpend' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppCreditSpend'),
                    'AppUtilitiesSpend' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppUtilitiesSpend'),
                    'AppFoodSpend' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppFoodSpend'),
                    'AppTransportSpend' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppTransportSpend'),
                    'AppOtherSpend' => $this->formatField($customer, 'AppOtherSpend'),
                    'BankName' => $this->formatField($customer, 'BankName'),
                    'BankSortcode' => $this->formatField($customer, 'BankSortcode'),
                    'BankAccount' => $this->formatField($customer, 'BankAccount'),
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        CakeLog::write('debug', "A: ".strlen($fields));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // Enable verbose output

        $string = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $res = json_decode($string, true);

        CakeLog::write('debug', json_encode($res));

        // success
        return $res;

    } catch (Exception $e) { }

    // it never saved
    return null;
}


max_input_vars applies to $_GET / $_POST. Since you are sending a JSON request here, that doesn't even apply to begin with.

"anything over 1024 causes curl to timeout and not send?" - can you show the actual output CURLOPT_VERBOSE produces here? Does the same thing happen when you try and send this to a different server?

The output is the typical CURL timeout exception. And no, if I manually make the same request to the server via Postman it works

It seems that when CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT is set to true that CURLOPT_VERBOSE doesn't work. See: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65348 I have not confirmed this behavior for PHP 7.4.

It won't hurt to add error checking. You're assuming that every step (encode JSON, submit HTTP request, decode JSON response) will work, so whenever it doesn't it's hard to tell what failed without plugging in a step debugger.
